# general query about joins in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know whether there's any difference between the queries below. More specifically, I am interested in the joins and what's the preferred way of inner joining '=' or the clause inner join. Thanks

```
        select distinct gsm.mobile_no, par.name par
        from ccare.customer cus, ccare.cu_partner par, service.contract contr, service.gsm gsm
        where par.code = cus.partner_code
        and contr.contract_no = gsm.contract_code
        and gsm.code = sgcp.code

        select distinct gsm.mobile_no, par.name par
        from ccare.customer cus 
        inner join ccare.cu_partner par on par.code = cus.partner_code 
        inner join service.contract contr on contr.contract_no = service.gsm.contract_code
        inner join charge.gsm_charge_plan sgcp on sgcp.service_code = gsm.code
```

Comment: Performance wise,there`s no difference.Explicit JOINs are easier to read.

Comment: Also you can check MySQL query execution plan (`EXPLAIN` command) for yourself here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: Just pretend that comma joins don't exist.

Comment: @user3017335 - When you use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause), it's **really easy** to miss a join condition (say, `gsm.code = sgcp.code`), and you end up not getting the results you expect; almost all RDBMSs _require_ the `ON` clause (so you have to specify at least one).  It also makes it easier to (mentally) group the conditions to the table that they belong to.  Note that things like `LEFT JOIN`s become difficult to write - you don't know the effect until the `WHERE`, and it's a lot easier to accidently get an `INNER JOIN` instead.... plus, I believe it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

These are just 2 different ways of joins.

First one is called **THETA** style of join while another one is known as **ANSI** style of join. Both are similar and it is up to you which method you choose.